# Detect client side redirect when crawling with Delphi TidHttp

Tags: php, html, delphi

I'm a Delphi developer and was tasked to do crawling of `<title>` and `meta` description and keywords for public facing websites.

It was fine until I encountered a website that self redirects and did not redirect with HTTP 302/301.

For example, if I type `example.com` in the url, it will automatically jump to `example-b.com` - but on the client side - not via HTTP 301 or 302.

My goal is to get title, description, and keywords of `example-b.com`.

I'm using TidHttp in delphi if that helps.

**Edit**

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961831/how-to-track-url-redirects-using-delphi-and-indy) but it was stated that will only work with HTTP 301 and 302. I have handled those redirects already. I'm trying to figure out how to handle `<meta>` refersh tags or other html commands that do redirects.

**Edit 2**

just found this commands :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://thisinterestsme.com/detecting-ajax-requests-with-php/">
header( "refresh:5;url=http://thisinterestsme.com/php-forcing-https-over-http/" );
header('Location: http://thisinterestsme.com/php-forcing-https-over-http/');
window.location.href= 'http://thisinterestsme.com/php-forcing-https-over-http/';
```

let me know if I missed other commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track URL redirects using Delphi and Indy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961831/how-to-track-url-redirects-using-delphi-and-indy)

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds ridicules but, "what is TDK" ?

Comment: @accountant, TDK = title, description and keyword

Answer (score 3):

`TIdHTTP` **does not** follow [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) redirects even if `HandleRedirects` is set to `True`. It does, however, parse `<meta http-equiv=...`, if `hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv` is not included in property `HTTPOptions` of `TIdHTTP`. By default the option is not included. After performing a request you can access parsed values via `IdHTTP.MetaHTTPEquiv` which is a shorthand for `IdHTTP.Response.MetaHTTPEquiv`.

Since Indy doesn't handle it, you have to do it yourself with all the burden of parsing URL from the value, performing the redirection and detecting cyclic/infinite redirections. The same goes for `Refresh` header which is not the part of [official standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header).

The `Location` header is only valid with HTTP status codes `201 Created`, `202 Accepted` and `3xx`. It should only redirect when status code is `3xx` (except `304 Not Modified`), which Indy already does, so you don't need to handle this in any special way.

And at last to support JavaScript redirections brings the task to much higher level of complexity, which `TIdHTTP` won't be able to crack. That seems to be the use case for a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser).